# how to set a character betwen other characters in php

Tags: php, numbers, clock

how to convert string sample 1 to sample 2 in PHP:

this string :     0510

after  :          05:10

thanks

Comment: dude, your question is TOO simple/hard to answer, you should throw in more details

Comment: <?php echo $stirng = "0510" // show 0510 but i want showing me 05:10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you added the "clock" tag, I assume you are talking about times. So you can use some date/time functions for this as well:

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime('0510'));
```

Output:

```
05:10
```

Answer (score 5):

Without giving more info, there are hundreds of ways to convert '0510' to '05:10'. You can use `.substr()`:

```
$string = '0510';
$string = substr($string, 0, 2).':'.substr($string, -2);
```

Or brackets:

```
$string = $string[0].$string[1].':'.$string[2].$string[3];
```

Or `.str_split()` with `.implode()`:

```
$string = implode(':', str_split($string, 2));
```

Or `.preg_replace()`:

```
$string = preg_replace(`~(\d{2})(\d{2})~`, '$1:$2', $string);
```

Comment: Great call on `str_split()`/`implode()` combo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about what you want but maybe you're looking for substr

```
$sample2 = substr($sample1, 0, 2) . ':' . substr($sample1, -2);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr()` to split the string into two and append them again.

```
$string = '0510';
$first = substr($string, 0, 2);
$second = substr($string, 2);

echo $first . ':' . $second
```

Comment: very thanks from All friends in forum ... this answer very sampled & worked ! thanks